# Appium for iOS takes too long to find an element on a screen which displays a video advertisement

Tags: java, ios, appium, appium-ios, xcuitest

I'm trying to find an element on a screen of an iOS native app which is an overlay that displays these components:

- A label with text as "Advertisement"
- A button with text "skip ad"
- A container in the middle which displays a video advertisement for around 10 seconds

The moment this overlay is displayed, I try to find an element with text as "Advertisement" as a way to identify that I'm on the correct screen.

The behaviour of this overlay is that it closes the moment the video advertisement finishes playing. Video duration is of ~ 10 seconds.

My script is:

```
driver.findElement(MobileBy.AccessibilityID("Advertisement"))
```

**What does the overlay look like?**

[image]

**What is the issue?**

1. findElement (from Appium Desktop) command takes too long to respond back with results. This is the Appium console log:
   [image]
2. If you notice the time it takes for the find element to finish execution is **16882 ms (16 seconds)** which is almost the same amount of time the video takes to play and finish.
3. **IMP:** The element is found (after the video completes) when I try to find it manually using Appium Desktop, but never found when I run an automated script. It gives an impression that Appium's process/request somehow gets blocked while the video is playing and resumes only when the video finishes.

Has anyone faced such similar issues with screens displaying video advertisements?